Conditional Expectation: Wikipedia's Example
In an attempt at grasping the concept of conditional expectation, I stumbled across the following example from Wikipedia:

I struggle to understand why the Random Variables $E(X|\mathcal{B})$ and $E(X|\mathcal{C})$ are constant in the minimal sets of the respective sub-$\sigma$-algebras.

If $\{P_1,P_2,...,P_n\}$ is a measurable partitoon of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal G$ is the $\sigma-$ algebra generated by this partition,  then $E[X|\mathcal G]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_k1_{P_k}$ where $c_k=\frac 1 {Pr(P_k)}\int_{P_k} XdP$. This can be verified from the definition of conditional expectations. In words, $E[X|\mathcal G]$ has the constant value $c_k$ on $P_k$ for $k=1,2...,n$.
More details: $\mathcal G$ is nothing but all possible unions of $P_i$'s. To verify that $\int_E XdP=\int_E \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_k1_{P_k}$ for every $E \in \mathcal G$, it is enough to prove this when $E=P_i$ for some $i$. But in this case, the equality is straightforward. [Of course, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_k1_{P_k}$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$].
